# Display the "for all" (∀) symbol in a plot

Tags: r, plot

I cannot get R to display the *for all* mathematical symbol (∀). How can I get the the *for all* mathematical symbol (∀) displayed in a plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
plot(0, main = ~ "prefix" ~  symbol("\042") ~ "suffix")
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice, but I have no idea how this works. Why is this a formula? What is the first tilde for? I searched a bit, but nothing useful came up. Any hint where to look?

Comment: A formula or expression can be used.  The first `~` is not really needed since its already a formula but I put it in for clarity.  The other `~` characters create spaces.  `* " suffix"` could be used in place of `~ suffix`, etc.  See `?plotmath` which specifically documents `symbol("\042")`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It also seems that prefix and suffix do not need to be quoted: `plot(0, main = ~ prefix ~ symbol("\042") ~ suffix)` is the same.